# Java application gives random outputs of an integer

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I have been having an issue with my Java application where I give the user a certain amount of "points" in the database for every time they complete an action. 32 database points is equal to one ingame point. On the event that the user does an action a method is run to see if the points are a multiple of 32, then says you have  skypoints after dividing the points from the database by 32. After the user completes the action a certain amount of times it stops working and returns 0 every time the user does an action, not even when it's a multiple of 32. Here is a screenshot of the output and the code is located below to give you an understanding of what I have.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code inside my database class

```
public long getPoints(String uuid) {
    long points = 0;
    try {
    // Open a connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    // Execute a query
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT playerpoints FROM SkyPoints.players WHERE playerid='" + uuid + "';";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
        points = rs.getLong("playerpoints") / 32;
    }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return points;
}

public long getRawPoints(String uuid) {
    long points = 0;
    try {
    // Open a connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    // Execute a query
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT playerpoints FROM SkyPoints.players WHERE playerid='" + uuid + "';";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
        points = rs.getLong("playerpoints");
    }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return points;
}
```

Code inside my main class

```
    if(DatabaseObject.getRawPoints(uuid) % 32 == 0) {
        String newamount = String.valueOf(DatabaseObject.getPoints(uuid));
        String word = null;
        if(DatabaseObject.getPoints(uuid) == 1) {
            word = "Point";
        } else {
            word = "Points";
        }
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "You have earned 1 Sky Point. New amount: " + ChatColor.BLUE + newamount + ChatColor.GRAY + " Sky " + word + ".");
    }
```

Note: UUID is the user id

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

UPDATE: Got an sql error

```
[16:58:42 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor58.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1116)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2338)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor44.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at me.andrewyunt.SkyPoints.Database.getPoints(Database.java:159)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at me.andrewyunt.SkyPoints.SkyPoints.onBlockBreak(SkyPoints.java:77)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:296)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerInteractManager.breakBlock(PlayerInteractManager.java:264)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerInteractManager.dig(PlayerInteractManager.java:118)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:550)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(SourceFile:53)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInBlockDig.handle(SourceFile:8)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:184)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:81)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:731)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:289)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:584)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:490)
[16:58:42 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628)
```

> Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

Comment: It's because you don't close your connections and after a bit it refuse to open more connections

Comment: That error's just because you are creating a new database connection each time you call either of your methods and never close them.  I can't see why it'd be relevant to the data error, but it's always a good idea to fix things you *know* to be wrong before spending more time looking for unknown issues.

Comment: I also noticed im creating too many connections instead of reusing.

Comment: You could avoid reusing, by simply closing it in a finally block. (it's better to open a connection when you need it and close when you are ok)

Comment: Well, on the try statement I put a finally block then I close the connection and it can't access the variable conn. So reusing is probably my best move.

Comment: You can't access it because it should be declared outside of the try block. Or you could use the try-with-resource statement. Learn these language basics. The Java tutorial explains them.

Comment: Should I put the finally after my catch statement?

Comment: I always forget about try-with-resources.  There's a good explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  If you're using java 7 or higher, this is much cleaner than try-catch-finally.

Comment: Not completely sure that this is proper code, but here is the updated version: http://pastebin.com/XsN4kbsL

Comment: The solution seems to have worked. I'll update this thread if anything goes wrong with it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please share it with us by __[answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)__ with the `Add An Answer` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your `Connections` and `ResultSets` after you are done with them, otherwise, it will be as if you're still executing queries with them, even though you aren't.

To close a `Connection` or `ResultSet`, just use `variableName.close();`. So, for example, you should use:

```
connection.close();
resultset.close();
```

In the case of your code, you should use:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
//set the query, create the statement

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
//get values

conn.close();
rs.close();

//return values
```

The reason you're getting the error is because MySQL thinks that you're still using all of those connections, even though you aren't. To make it so MySQL doesn't think you're still using those connections, is to close them, with `connection.close()`.